# Batch file to compare versions of MSI file and Installed version

Tags: windows, batch-file, vbscript, windows-installer, version

I have an install script currently that only installs if the product isn't already installed (by checking for the presence of the app's EXE), but I'd like to take it a step further and have it only install if the MSI version is newer than the installed version. And although it would be nice for the script to query the MSI for this, if this isn't possible, I could always update the MSI version in a variable within the script...but it would be nice if it was active query that didn't need to be always updated.

I haven't been able to find anything that can get me the MSI version, and the only place I've seen the MSI version is when I do look at File Properties -> Details -> Subject line: Product XYZ 10.2.3.

For checking the installed version, I've found:

```
wmic datafile where name='c:\\windows\\system32\\notepad.exe' get version
```

Which returns two lines, second of which is 10,2,3 (using comma's instead of decimals).

If I use:

```
wmic product where "name like 'Product XYZ%%'" get version
```

I get the same result but in the expected decimal format, but the query takes MUCH longer to run. But in either case, I still need to figure out how to actually work off the queried result.

This might be easier with a VBS, which I'm ok with, as long as I can call it within my existing batch file as well as work off the VBS result within my batch file.

Thanks in advance!
Brian

Answer (score 0):

This shows the principal of extracting specific info using findstr.

```
@echo off

If "%~1"=="" goto help
If "%~1"=="/?" goto help
If /i "%~1"=="/h" goto help
If "%~1"=="-?" goto help
If /i "%~1"=="-h" goto help

set filepath=%~f1
set  file=%filepath:\=\\%
wmic datafile where name^="%file%" get version|findstr /i /v /c:"version"
echo %errorlevel%
goto finish

:help
Echo.
Echo. FileVer
Echo. -------
Echo.
Echo.    By David Candy 2013
Echo.
Echo. Purpose:
Echo.
Echo.    Reports the version number for an exe, dll, and similar files.
Echo.
Echo. Usage:
Echo.
Echo.    filever ^<executable file^>
Echo.
Echo.    filever [/h ^| -h ^| /? ^| -?]    Starts this help
Echo.
echo. Examples:
Echo.
Echo.    filever c:\windows\explorer.exe
Echo.    filever "C:\Program Files\Windows NT\Accessories\wordpad.exe"
Echo.    filever shell32.dll

Echo.
Echo.    For Help
Echo.
Echo.    filever 

Echo.    filever /?
Echo.

:finish
rem Pause if command double clicked
If /i "%cmdcmdline:~0,6%"=="cmd /c" pause
```

And this shows using For

```
set service=%1
for /f "skip=1 tokens=1,2,3* delims= " %%a in ('sc getkeyname %service%') do echo %%c
```

Comment: OK, the first section works perfectly fine and outputs the version number (then a blank line, and "0" (errorlevel I'm assuming)). But I'm having a hard time figuring out the FOR statement. I've tried modifying it, but don't get the result I'm looking for. If I just copy/paste your version, the FOR statement echo's "service" on the line after the "0". If I just run the WMIC command:
C:\>wmic datafile where name='c:\\application.exe' get version
This is the output:
Version (line1)
1.2.456.78 (line2)

Comment: Sorry, don't like this commenting system's lack of formatting (or me not understanding it). I'm just looking for the FOR statement to pull out the "1.2.456.78" and using that as a variable that I can then compare against a static value for the MSI (since I can't find anything like this that will work for MSI file). And not sure if it matters, but the "1.2.456.78" can change in length, as sometimes the 3rd section ("456") can be only 1 digit.

Answer (score 0):

here's a way using `makecab` :

```
; @echo off
;;goto :end_help
;;setlocal DsiableDelayedExpansion
;;;
;;;
;;; fileinf /l list of full file paths separated with ;
;;; fileinf /f text file with a list of files to be processed ( one on each line )
;;; fileinf /? prints the help
;;;
;;:end_help

; REM Creating a Newline variable (the two blank lines are required!)
; set NLM=^


; set NL=^^^%NLM%%NLM%^%NLM%%NLM%
; if "%~1" equ "/?" type "%~f0" | find ";;;" | find /v "find" && exit /b 0
; if "%~2" equ "" type "%~f0" | find ";;;" | find /v "find" && exit /b 0
; setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
; if "%~1" equ "/l" (
;  set "_files=%~2"
;  echo !_files:;=%NL%!>"%TEMP%\file.paths"
;  set _process_file="%TEMP%\file.paths"
;  goto :get_info
; )

; if "%~1" equ "/f" if exist "%~2" (
;  set _process_file="%~2"
;  goto :get_info
; )

; echo incorect parameters & exit /b 1
; :get_info
; set "file_info="

; makecab /d InfFileName=%TEMP%\file.inf /d "DiskDirectory1=%TEMP%" /f "%~f0"  /f %_process_file% /v0>nul

; for /f "usebackq skip=4 delims=" %%f in ("%TEMP%\file.inf") do (
;  set "file_info=%%f"
;  echo !file_info:,=%nl%!
; )

; endlocal
;endlocal
; del /q /f %TEMP%\file.inf 2>nul
; del /q /f %TEMP%\file.path 2>nul
; exit /b 0

.set DoNotCopyFiles=on
.set DestinationDir=;
.set RptFileName=nul
.set InfFooter=;
.set InfHeader=;
.Set ChecksumWidth=8
.Set InfDiskLineFormat=;
.Set Cabinet=off
.Set Compress=off
.Set GenerateInf=ON
.Set InfDiskHeader=;
.Set InfFileHeader=;
.set InfCabinetHeader=;
.Set InfFileLineFormat=",file:*file*,date:*date*,size:*size*,csum:*csum*,time:*time*,vern:*ver*,vers:*vers*,lang:*lang*"
```

Here's an example if the script is called `fileinfo.bat`

```
c:> fileinfo.bat /l C:\install.exe
    file:install.exe
    date:11/07/07
    size:562688
    csum:380ef239
    time:07:03:18a
    vern:9.0.21022.8
    vers:9.0.21022.8 built by: RTM
    lang:1033
```

Answer (score 0):

You could adapt this script maybe. The pver variable is the version string and pname tells you the name. There's a lot more you can do with vbs because there's an entire scripting engine that starts with the Installer object. Sorry about the formatting, haven't masterd thet on SO.

Option Explicit

Public installer, fullmsg, comp, prod, a, fso, pname, ploc, pid, psorce, pcache, pver

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set a = fso.CreateTextFile("prods.txt", True)

' Connect to Windows Installer object
Set installer = CreateObject("WindowsInstaller.Installer")
a.writeline ("Products")
on error resume next
For Each prod In installer.products

pid = installer.productinfo (prod, "ProductID")

pname = installer.productinfo (prod, "ProductName")

pver = installer.productinfo (prod, "VersionString")

psorce=installer.productinfo(prod, "InstallSource")

ploc = installer.productinfo (prod, "InstallLocation")
 pcache = installer.productinfo(prod, "LocalPackage") 
   a.writeline (prod & " " & pname & " Version " & pver & " installed at " & ploc & " from " & psorce & " cached at " & pcache)

Next